# How show if another user are the same XPages

Tags: ajax, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I need a custom control that show Like Google Docs into the top of my Page
...if another user see the currently XPages...

Have someone any suggest to realize this feature?

Into JSF runtime there are a List of XPages opened in all session?

Answer (score 1):

Check out my openntf project document Locker

http://www.openntf.org/Internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPage%20Document%20Locker

You could use this to lock the document but with a little modification you could also see people on the same Xpage. 
Add people when they enter the xpage, remove them when they exit.

Comment: Tnx you very much, I have see you Custom Control into OpenNtf.org.
The problem is that How can I capture the Users that exit (with button close of the browser?)
All work if my users use apposite Button that Unlock the ID...have you any suggest?
If the user don't use apposite button (usually "Close" button) I'm afraid that I have much locked document in my application :-(

Comment: @DanieleGrillo: Don't caputure if they leave the page. Create a PartialRefresh or JSON-RPC Call (or a websocket call) which updates every X seconds if a user has the page still open in the browser.

Comment: @Sven Hasselbach: hmmm....hmmm....ok...Partial Refresh is a good method for test Keep-alive ( Xhr.get() in Dojo language ) but.I don't undestard..the scenario is:
The user "Daniele Grillo" open a page "Test.xsp" and every 3 second test with Ajax Call if the page is open...
When the user open the XPages into beforeOpenPage event execute doc.islock() 
In concurrency Sven Hasselbech open the same page "Test.xsp" and he see that another user locked this page so can't press the button "Modify"

If Daniele Grillo close the Browser (so don't execute Unlock feature)...how Sven as it does to notice?

Comment: @DanieleGrillo: If you save the information *Page*, *UserName*, *TimeStamp* in an application scoped variable or a managed bean you can then display the current user visiting the current XPage. When updating the value with a PR or JSON-RPC you will have a method which allows you to track if a user has left the page (closing the browser / shutting down the computer / whatever). Just clean up the list of users / xpages if last update is older than X+Y seconds.

Comment: The User "Sven" will get the information that all other users have closed the XPage with the Ajax Call (The list now contains only his name). You can now re-enable the "Modify" Button.

Comment: If your users are only using IE and Firefox the onunload event could be used to remove users leaving the page.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp

Comment: @Sven Hasselbeach: tnx you for your suggest...I understand that with **TimeStamp** and elapsed time second is the solution for monitoring if the user is loggend in a particular page. Tnx you very much. now I try